# How to compare two comma-separated strings, and return false untill and unless all values matched

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
suppose @v1 = p1;p2;p3;p4
@v2 = p1;p2;p3
@v3= p1;p2;p3;p4
```

i have to compare the values of @v2 and @v3 with the values of @v1.
I need a function that will return TRUE if there is a match of all values . So in the above example,   it would return TRUE in case of @v3 and returns false in case of @v2.

I am trying to write a code..but its not working.
i am mentioning the code here.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM dbo.Split(@v1) AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.Split(@v2) AS b
    ON a.Item = b.Item
)
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;


how can it be possible in sql server? plz help.
```

Comment: Delimited strings are *not* a natural way to work with multiple values in SQL Server - SQL Server has two data types that are *designed* to hold multiple values - XML and tables - could you not switch to using one of those instead?

Answer (score 0):

For all value match you can go with equal operator:

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(20) = 'p1;p2;p3;p4'
DECLARE @v2 VARCHAR(20) = 'p1;p2;p3'
DECLARE @v3 VARCHAR(20) = 'p1;p2;p3;p4'

IF @v1 = @v2
  PRINT 'V1=V2'
ELSE IF @v1 = @v3
  PRINT 'V1=V3' 

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
    FROM dbo.Split(@v1) AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.Split(@v2) AS b
    ON a.Item = b.Item)
SELECT 1
ELSE
SELECT 0
```

Assuming that your function is table valued.

Answer (score 0):

I have revised my answer after testing:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CommaListsAreEqual
(
    @CommaList1 varchar(1000),
    @CommaList2 varchar(1000)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Retval INT;
  WITH 
    Table1 (Item) 
    AS 
    (
      SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@CommaList1, ',')
    ),
    Table2 (Item)  
    AS 
    (
      SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@CommaList2, ',')
    )
     SELECT
       @Retval = COUNT(*)
     FROM
       Table1
       FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Item = Table2.Item
     WHERE
       Table1.Item IS NULL 
       OR
       Table2.Item IS NULL


   RETURN CASE WHEN @Retval = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

END
GO

-- Tests:
SELECT dbo.CommaListsAreEqual('1,2,3', '1,2,3') -- Should return 1
SELECT dbo.CommaListsAreEqual('1,2,3', '1,2,5') -- Should return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Checks(@v1 VARCHAR(100),@v2 VARCHAR(100),@v3 VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
AS
  BEGIN
      RETURN
        (SELECT Count(1)
         FROM   (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') col
                 FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@v1, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS f
                        CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) fst
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM   (SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') col
                                    FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@v2, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                                           CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
                                    UNION
                                    SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') col
                                    FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@v3, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                                           CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) kl
                            WHERE  fst.col = kl.col))
  END

DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(100) = 'p1;p2;p3;p4',
        @v2 VARCHAR(100) = 'p1;p2;p3;p4',
        @v3 VARCHAR(100) = 'p1;p2;p3'

SELECT CASE WHEN dbo.Checks(@v1, @v2, @v3) = 0 THEN 'MATCHED' ELSE 'NOT MATCHED' END [Check]
-- OUTPUT : 'MATCHED'

DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR(100) = 'p1;p2;p3;p4',
        @v2 VARCHAR(100) = 'p1;p2;p3',
        @v3 VARCHAR(100) = 'p1;p2;p3'

SELECT CASE WHEN dbo.Checks(@v1, @v2, @v3) = 0 THEN 'MATCHED' ELSE 'NOT MATCHED' END [Check]
-- OUTPUT : 'NOT MATCHED'
```